# How to change the fontsize of xtick and xlabel separately in matlab heatmap?

Tags: matlab, heatmap, matlab-figure

I was using the matlab function `heatmap` and I got the following figure.
[image: heatmap]

The fontsize of 0, 0.05, ..., are fine. But I want to make xlabel 'Drive conversion rate' bigger.

```
h = heatmap(x_values, y_values, heatmap_values',  'MissingDataColor', 'w', 'GridVisible', 'off', 'MissingDataLabel', " ", 'CellLabelColor', 'none', 'ColorMethod', 'mean', 'ColorbarVisible','off');
title('Standard');
xlabel('Female drive fitness');
ylabel('Embryo resistance rate');
s = struct(h);
s.XAxis.TickLabelRotation = 60;
s.Axes.Title.FontSize = 8;
s.XAxis.FontSize = 5.5;
s.YAxis.FontSize = 5.5;
```

This is my current code. s.XAxis.FontSize always change the fontsize of xticks and xlabel at the same time. And s.xLabel does not have a FontSize parameter. Is there a method to change the fontsize of xticks and xlabel separately?

Comment: The example in the docs for `xlabel` [right here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlabel.html#d126e1806478) show `xlabel(…,'FontSize',12)`.

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately there is no option in current version of Matlab, however you can add another invisible axis to the same figure and set a completely different xlabel with font size to that axis. you can use code below:

```
% Create axes
axes('Parent', gcf);
axis off

% Create xlabel
xlabel('xlabel','PickableParts','all','FontSize',20,'Visible','on');
```

and since the xlabel is probably outpositioned, you need to set the position of xlabel manually either.